Sticky button stickied left taking up whole width?
Hello I have a button that is stickied to the bottom left but taking up whole space for some reason. Commenting display: flex and flex-direction: column in .todo-list does not allow the plus button to stay stickied to the bottom of the container on the container resize

Button:
<div className="todo-list">            
    <button className="add-task-button" onClick={handleShowInput}>
        <img src={addIcon} alt="Add Task" className="add-icon" />
    </button>
</div>

Style:
.todo-list {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;


    p {
        margin: 0 0 0 2.4em;
    }

    ul {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .add-task-button {
        position: sticky;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        height: auto;
        bottom: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        width: auto;

        .add-icon {
            width: 2.2em;
            
        }

        &:hover {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
    }
}

Please help as you are my only hope anymore

you didn't show the css for the container. But I am guessing it has flex display with flex-direction as column. So every child item will have entire width. If you want to show something else beside the button just add it in same div.

The width in your style can be given a fixed width
